# appearing blank space below footer in WordPress website after adding CSS code ( transform: rotate(-6deg)} )

Tags: html, css, wordpress

On a WordPress website, in (section -> column -> inner section -> column -> heading) added marquee text by adding below HTML code in (section -> column)
& also added CSS Class in an inner section

> sliding-text

& duplicate the inner section
in order to reverse the flow of the second line, I added CSS Class in a duplicate inner section

> sliding-text reverse

But I also want to tilt the text a little too (-6deg) which only works for the first line so I also added

> selector{ transform: rotate(-6deg)}

which leads to blank space below the footer and when I remove the (transform: rotate(-6deg)}) code blank space is also removed
[image: marquee text with right side scroll bar & i only have 3 sections in this page]

```
<style>
body{
--speed: 15s;
}
.sliding-text .elementor-widget-wrap{
transform: rotate(-6deg);
}
.sliding-text .elementor-widget-wrap{
display: block !important;
}
.sliding-text .elementor-widget{
overflow: hidden;
width: 10000vw !important;
max-width: 10000vw !important;
}
.sliding-text .sliding .elementor-widget-container{
-webkit-animation: sliding var(--speed) linear infinite;
-moz-animation: sliding var(--speed) linear infinite;
-o-animation: sliding var(--speed) linear infinite;
animation: sliding var(--speed) linear infinite;
}
.sliding-text .elementor-widget-container{
float: left;
}
.sliding-text.reverse .elementor-widget-wrap{
transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.sliding-text.reverse .sliding .elementor-heading-title{
transform: scale(-1, -1);
}
@keyframe sliding{
0%{ transform: translateX(0); }
100%{ transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
@-webkit-keyframes sliding {
0%{ transform: translateX(0); }
100%{ transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
@-moz-keyframes sliding {
0%{ transform: translateX(0); }
100%{ transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
@-o-keyframes sliding {
0%{ transform: translateX(0); }
100%{ transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
@keyframes sliding {
0%{ transform: translateX(0); }
100%{ transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
var $ = jQuery
$(document).ready(function(){
var h = []
$('.sliding-text').each(function(){
    h.push($(this).find('.elementor-widget').clone().html())
})

function init(){
    $('.sliding-text').each(function(i){
        var $this = $(this)
        $this.find('.elementor-widget').removeClass('sliding')
        var amount = Math.ceil($(window).width()/$(this).find('.elementor-widget-container').outerWidth(true)) + 1
        $this.find('.elementor-widget').empty().addClass('sliding')
        $this.find('.elementor-widget').html(h[i].repeat(amount))
    })  
}

init()
$(window).on('load resize', init)
})
</script>
```

[image: below image is showing after blank space after footer and a lot to scroll]

Comment: Please add the HTML for your CSS so we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: I have written the whole HTML text above and all the steps i have done

Comment: You didn't write any necessary HTML text in your question. Only  `<script>` and `<style>` . Please add the relevant part to your question.

Comment: actually, I want to do a little customization in a marquee so I added only this part through HTML code and rest is from elementor

Comment: Doesn't matter if it is from elementor (whatever that is, something from wordpress?) or whatever. If you don't want to post the code we are not able to help you. Like at all.

Comment: https://makedreamwebsite.com/create-a-auto-sliding-scrolling-text-effect-in-elementor/

Comment: please go through the above link I follow that to get the marquee in WordPress just i want a little more effect to add

Comment: wanted to make marquee text a little tilted

Comment: As stated now 3 times, you need to post all relevant code to the question. See also: 
[Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

Add the following CSS:

```
.elementor.elementor-1535 {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

it should fix the issue.

Comment: nope not working I guess it is something to do css code

Comment: https://makedreamwebsite.com/create-a-auto-sliding-scrolling-text-effect-in-elementor/

Comment: above is the link I follow to add marquee text, but I want to do a little extra, I also want to tilt text to (-6deg) please go through it, perhaps you could get some other way

Comment: Do you have a publicly available page, where we can  see the issue?

Comment: and above is the link I followed exactly to add marquee text on my page just wanted to add a little more effect, to tilt (-6deg)

Comment: I've updated the code. Take a look. Cheers!